Selecting Polygons that have x% within another polygon using QGIS
I am using QGIS.
I have a vectorized radio coverage polygon layer for a radio transmitter, and a polygon layer showing neighbourhoods.  I want to be able to select neighboorhoods that are mostly (variable threshold) covered by the radio transmitter.  I can use select by location to find neighbourhoods that are 100% covered by the radio transmitter, but I would like to figure out how to find neighbourhoods where most or almost all are covered.
In the picture, radio coverage is shown in green.  Neighbourhoods are red with opacity so show brown where they overlap.  I have drawn blue areas over some neighbourhoods that are almost fully covered except for a tiny fraction, and these of course fail my selection using the within parameter.
As an example, if I wanted to select neighbourhoods where 95% overlap the radio coverage, how might I do this?


Look at the Overlay Analysis tool.

@user105727, don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted if your problem has been solved. This makes it easier for other users to find answers if they have similar questions down the track.

Check out the overlap analysis tool in the QGIS processing toolbox. It calculates the area and percentage cover by which features from an input layer are overlapped by features from one or more overlay layers.
Once the percentage overlap is calculated, you can filter on the percentage wanted...

You can use Select Features using an expression  :
(area(
intersection($geometry, 
make_valid(
collect_geometries(
overlay_intersects( layer:='radio coverage', expression:=$geometry))))) / $area )>0.95

Replace radio coverage with the name of your radio coverage layer. The expression intersects each neighborhood polygon with a union of all intersecting radio polygons, and calculates the area overlap proportion.

